# Pass id in component

Tags: reactjs

I can´t figure it out how to pass `id` as a prop in `SimplePopper` component.

I have this table:

```
<TableBody>
  {PostData.map((list, index) => (
    <TableRow key={index}>
      <TableCell>{list.first_name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{list.last_name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell><SimplePopper key="{list.id}" /></TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))}
</TableBody>
```

I want to pass `id` to `SimplePopper`:

```
function PostPopover() {
  
    return (
        <div>
            {PostData.map((list, index)=>{
                return <div key="id"> {list.email} </div>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default function SimplePopper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'simple-popper' : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <button aria-describedby={id} type="button" onClick={handleClick} color="primary">
        Show email
      </button>
      <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
        <div className={classes.paper}><PostPopover />.</div>
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is PostData data structure:

```
[{"id":1,
"first_name":"Geraldine",
"last_name":"Graal",
"email":"ggraal0@indiegogo.com"},
{"id":2,
"first_name":"Farris",
"last_name":"Sowten",
"email":"fsowten1@blogger.com"}]
```

I know the mistake is in `PostPopover` because I got te full email list but no just the email related to the id, but can't figure it out why. Any idea?

Comment: Are you saying that `PostPopover` is the same component rendering the table in the first snippet? Have you tried passing `id` as a prop? Can you post the *actual* code you have an issue with? Also, you can't use `key="id"` because all the mapped elements would have the same react key, an invalid use of them.

Comment: @DrewReese That's `SimplePopper`added.

Comment: Which `id` are you trying to pass? You've an `id` in each element in your `PostData`, and another declared in `SimplePopper`? Can you clarify which one you are tying to pass as a prop and where?

Answer (score 3):

You can just pass the id to `ShowPopper` as :

```
<ShowPopper id={list.id} />
```

Now you can access it in `ShowPopper` in `props` as:

```
const ShowPopper =(props) => {
 console.log(props.id);
 return <div>{props.id}</div>
}
```